# Change vm instances asia-east2-b zone to asia-south-b zone - Google Clud (Compute Engine)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I realize that I selected the wrong Region zone and now I have to correct that. Can you tell me how is it possible? My current project is live in vm instances asia-east2-b zone. I want to bring this asia-south-b zone now.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to move your instance from zone `asia-east2-b` to `asia-south1-b`.

Have a look at the documentation [Moving an instance between zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones):

> Whenever possible, you should [move an instance automatically](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-automatically)
>   using the projects.moveInstance API. If [you cannot use the API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#limitations),
>   you can still [move your instance manually](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually) using the following
>   steps:
>
> 1. Create snapshots of persistent disks attached to the original instance.
> 2. Create copies of the persistent disks in the destination zone.
> 3. For external and internal IP addresses:
>
>    - If you are moving an instance across zones within the same region, and you want to preserve its ephemeral IP address, temporarily promote
>        the ephemeral IP address that is assigned to the instance to a static
>        IP address and then assign it to the new VM instance you create in the
>        destination zone.
>    - If you are moving an instance across regions, you must pick a different IP address for the VM instance.
> 4. Create and boot up a new instance in the destination zone. If you are moving across regions, you must also pick a new subnetwork for the
>      new instance.
> 5. Attach the new persistent disks to your new instance.
> 6. Assign an external IP address to the new instance. If necessary, demote the address back to an ephemeral external IP address.
> 7. Delete the snapshots, original disks, and original instance.

and at the section [Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#limitations):

> Specifically, the following scenarios require a manual move: ...
>
> - You want to move your instance between regions, such as between us-west1-a and asia-south1-b, and your VM belongs to a subnetwork. You
>     must perform the move manually and select a new subnetwork for your
>     instance.

So, **because you want to move your VM instance between [regions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones#locations) you should move it manually** by following step by step instructions provided at section [Moving an instance manually](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones#moving-an-instance-manually).

In addition, have a look at the documentation [Reserving Compute Engine zonal resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources), it could be quite useful in some cases in compare to on-demand usage, but extra fee required.